CCXT fetch_closed_orders
I need to receive all orders or clodes_orders from Binance with CCXT. But closed orders need to be given symbols. I want to take all orders. How can I get all closed orders or all orders from binance to make it faster
If I go through all the possible symbols, it takes a very long time
async def fetch_orders(self, since_timestamp):
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
        self.binance.options["warnOnFetchOpenOrdersWithoutSymbol"] = False
        open_orders = await self.binance.fetch_closed_orders(since=since_timestamp)
        return open_orders
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching orders: {str(e)}")
        return []

    finally:
        await self.binance.close()

